# unexpected order of items in list from generator

Tags: python, generator

The below code creates a list of the indices of `'.'` in a string using a generator.

```
def gen(s):
    dot_index = 0
    while dot_index >= 0:
        dot_index = s.find('.', dot_index + 1)
        yield dot_index

def get_dots():
    s = '23.00 98.00 99.00'
    l = [s.find('.', i + 1) for i in gen(s)]
    print(l)

get_dots()
```

I would expect the order of the list to be [2, 8, 14, -1], but the actual order is [8, 14, -1, 2].

Please explain why the first index, 2, is last in the list.

This is probably due to a poor understanding of generators on my part.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generator return the order that you expect, the problem is that in `get_dots()` you get the index of the first dot, and then you search for the next dot `[s.find('.', i + 1) for i in gen(s)]`:

```
def gen(s):
    dot_index = 0
    while dot_index >= 0:
        dot_index = s.find('.', dot_index + 1)
        yield dot_index

def get_dots():
    s = '23.00 98.00 99.00'
    l = list(gen(s))
    print(l)

get_dots()
```

Comment: Dumb mistake on my part. Thanks.